# How to select an iFrame witth Dynamic ID with robot framework in PyCharm please?

Tags: iframe, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

[Here is the iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEZUk.png)

`<iframe src="User/UserAccounts" id="7969e06b-e259-82e7-ee38-fdac0a745e4a_iframe" frameborder="0" marginwidth="10" style="width: 823px; height: 744px;" onload="setTimeout(SSWindow.DocumentReady('#7969e06b-e259-82e7-ee38-fdac0a745e4a_iframe'), 20);"></iframe>`

id="7969e06b-e259-82e7-ee38-fdac0a745e4a_iframe

7969e06b-e259-82e7-ee38-fdac0a745e4a = this part is changing every reload

I Tried the below but it doesn't work.
//span[@class='bodyIframe']
//span[contains(text(),'_Iframe')]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any other attribute also could be used if its value is unique and constant over reloadings.

E.g. `src` attribute with the value "User/UserAccounts" probably could be useful here.

And respectively using keyword `select frame` to select frame if you use library [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame).
For example:

```
Select frame  //iframe[@src="User/UserAccounts"]
```